# Why am I getting different outputs for the same piece of code in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

## I am getting different outputs for the same lines of code in Node.js, running on a Windows machine.

I have just started out with Node.JS and was playing around a bit. I ran the following code multiple times, and, surprisingly got two different outputs (on the terminal, as well as the text file).
I do have some knowledge about JavaScript being asynchronous, but I did not expect two different outputs for the same lines of code.

```
const fs=require('fs');
const path=require('path');
console.log("Blah blah");
fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,'temp.txt'),'Hello!',(err)=>
{
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    console.log('Write complete.');
    fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname,'temp.txt'),'Bye-bye!',(err)=>
    {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        console.log('Inner append');
    });
});
fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname,'temp.txt'),'Hi, again!',(err)=>
{
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    console.log('Outer append');
});
```

I am getting the following two outputs, along with the contents of the text file:

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmMPr.png)

First Output:

```
Blah blah
Write complete.
Outer append
Inner append
```

Second Output:

```
Blah blah
Outer append
Write complete.
Inner append
```

Contents of the text file corresponding to the first output:

```
Hello!Hi, again!Bye-bye!
```

Contents of the text file corresponding to the second output:

```
Hello!ain!Bye-bye!
```

I was expecting the second output, but the corresponding content of the text file doesn't really make sense. Please do point out if I have any conceptual misunderstanding and the reason behind two different outputs for the same code. My Node version is v18.16.0.

Please note that I am getting different outputs for the same environment, unlike similar questions with the same problem, but with different environments.

Thanks in advance!